# How do I get logs of active users in a Laravel application?

Tags: php, logging, laravel-5

I am developing an applications and was wondering how can I get logs of users active in the application. Also, when they clicked and landed on any page/view. The information I would want is the:

1. user's IP address of the machine,
2. time they went to that page and if possible when they left the page.
3. the name of the user
4. the section where they are.

From basic PHP I would do this by having a header PHP script on every page that does this and inserts in to a database. Question how can I achieve this in Laravel?

Would someone kindly lead me.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should do it with laravel events and handlers.

But there are good packages that you can use with just few lines of code!

like [this one](https://github.com/spatie/activitylog) !